# Should proper nouns be hyphenated if used as compound adjectives?

Tags: adjectives, hyphenation, proper-nouns

Which of the following two is correct, if any?

1. I watched a Six Nations rugby match.
2. I watched a Six-Nations rugby match.

Is there a general rule for the use of hyphens in compound adjectives when the adjective is derived from a proper noun?

Comment: Yes; look up on the internet to find normal usage. 'Six Nations' here is not an adjective but a [compound] noun used attributively. / The usual practice here is to use the premodifier in the same style as normal ('The Six Nations refers to six ...'), only adding a  hyphen if necessary to disambiguate. Since most proper open compounds are clearly compounds, the hyphen won't be needed often if at all (unless normally present).

Comment: "Six nations" is not an adjective, not a compound, but a nominal functioning as a modifier. To qualify as a compound it would need a hyphen, but I can't see any reason to analyse it as a compound. The term 'open compound' is a misnomer since separate words form a syntactic construction, not a morphological compound. "Six Nations Rugby Match" is a noun phrase with the nominal "Six Nations" being a pre-head modifier of "match".

Answer (score -1):

The general rule is that if a compound adjective is formed from proper nouns, it should not be hyphenated.

"Examples of Compound Adjectives from Proper Nouns.
Sometimes, compound adjectives are formed from proper nouns (i.e., the names of things), and these are written using capital letters. With such compound adjectives, there is no need to group the words using hyphens. For example:
Did you manage to get the Billy Elliot tickets?
(The words "Billy Elliot" are one adjective describing the tickets. As the capital letters group the words, there is no need to use a hyphen.)"

https://yc.yccd.edu/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/CompoundAdjectivesAccessibleMarch2019.pdf

Comment: Those are not adjectives.

Comment: @tchrist Then what are they? Are you saying that proper nouns should be hyphenated?

Comment: There are no adjectives in *Billy Elliot tickets*. You have confused adjectives and modifiers. The former is a part of speech, the latter a grammatical role. *Billy Elliot* is still nominal, never adjectival. This is trivially proven: *Billy Elliot*  cannot be modified by adverbs like *often* or *frequently* nor by intensifiers like *very* or *extremely*. It remains a noun even when used attributively the way it is here.

Comment: @tchrist I did not say there were adjectives in that sentence. I simply described the process of forming a compound adjective from a proper noun. I will ask you again. Should proper nouns be hyphenated or not?

Comment: You called it an adjective. This is wrong.

Comment: @tchrist No, I did not. I reiterate, I described the process of how a proper adjective is formed. It is trivially proven that adjectives that come from proper nouns are capitalized and need not be hyphenated.

Comment: Exactly what part of `Did you manage to get the Billy Elliot tickets? (The words "Billy Elliot" are one adjective describing the tickets.` is not pretending that Billy Elliot is an adjective when it isn't?

Comment: @tchrist What is the difference between a compound adjective and a compound modifier?